# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')' in

Tags: php, wordpress

I  want to code some associative array from database in this way.But it creates some error.
I want to know what are the faults.

```
 var $example_data = array(

            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
            array(
                'ID'         => $user->ID,
                'Name'       => $user->display_name,
                'Email'      => $user->user_email,
                'Phone'      => ''
            ),}


        );
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot code a foreach INSIDE an array declaration.

Try this instead

```
$example_data = array();    //initialize a valiable as an array

foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    $example_data[] =  array(
                           'ID'         => $user->ID,
                           'Name'       => $user->display_name,
                           'Email'      => $user->user_email,
                           'Phone'      => ''
                       );
}
```

**EDIT**: Stand alone test mockup, run in PHP CLI

```
<?php

// mockup the data
$user_query = new stdClass();
$t = new stdClass();
$t->ID = 1;
$t->display_name = 'aaa';
$t->user_email = 'aaa';
$user_query->results[] = $t;
$t = new stdClass();
$t->ID = 2;
$t->display_name ='bbb';
$t->user_email = 'bbb';
$user_query->results[] = $t;
//show the data
echo 'DATA Going into the foreach loop'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($user_query);


$example_data = array();    //initialize a valiable as an array

foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    $example_data[] =  array(
                           'ID'         => $user->ID,
                           'Name'       => $user->display_name,
                           'Email'      => $user->user_email,
                           'Phone'      => ''
                       );
}
// Show the result
echo 'Contents of $example_data'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($example_data);
```

RESULTS IN THIS OUTPUT:

```
DATA Going into the foreach loop
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [display_name] => aaa
                    [user_email] => aaa
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [display_name] => bbb
                    [user_email] => bbb
                )

        )

)
Contents of $example_data
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Name] => aaa
            [Email] => aaa
            [Phone] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => bbb
            [Email] => bbb
            [Phone] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in

Comment: Woops, I just copies your code and forgot to remove the `var`, fixed now.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$example_data' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in **

Comment: That code works, I have just mocked up a test, so your error is caused by something else. So I guess you dropped it into your code badly.

Answer (score 0):

the array in which you are putting your values($user variable) should have some name ,so first define it like this->

```
$test_array = array();
```

**here test_array is the name of that array variable and u can not name a variable with the language keywords**

```
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        $test_array(
            'ID'         => $user->ID,
            'Name'       => $user->display_name,
            'Email'      => $user->user_email,
            'Phone'      => ''
        );
}
```